# Why the Websense blocks same site when used with http & not when used https?

Tags: tls, firewalls, http, proxy, network-access-control

I have been working in a IT firm. I have access to some social sites. When I try to open site Links in mail (that are having http://), the websense prompts me that the access is blocked.
However, when i try to open same site using https, it opens without blocking ?

Answer (score 1):

"Websense" is a number versions of several different products, and without knowing which one is in use, I can't say for certain what the reason is that HTTPS connections are getting through.  However, there are a couple of likely candidates:

1) Some Websense software does not have HTTPS proxy capabilities.  Without this ability, the Websense software cannot read the requests to see what page is being requested.  All it can see is that a connection is being made to a given IP address, which greatly limits the ability to filter (it can only filter by physical server, not by domain or URL).

2) Other Websense software can proxy HTTPS connections, by providing its own SSL certificate and acting as a man-in-the-middle attacker.  In this case, HTTPS connections aren't being filtered because the software simply hasn't been configured to do so.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is more secure and limits the ability of attackers to snoop or modify your connection. The filtering seems to be configured for both security concerns and content accessing.